# TensorFlow: How to merge multiple 'collections'?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I have some `collections` that I would like to track with TensorBoard using a supervisor. In the Supervisor initializer I would like something to the effect

```
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all(['test', 'valid'])
```

But I get the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`, because the `key` must be a string ([see documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/summary/generation_of_summaries_#merge_all)).

---

**Edit**:

This doesn't work either:

```
summary_op = [tf.summary.merge_all('train'), tf.summary.merge_all('valid')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `tf.summary.merge()`, e.g. like so:

```
summary_op = tf.summary.merge([
        tf.summary.merge_all('test'),
        tf.summary.merge_all('train')],
    collections='merged')
```

This would merge all summaries from the `test` and `train` collections and add them to a new `merged` collection. Keep in mind that this will result in strange effects if the *same* summary is used multiple times during the *same* time step:

[image: Same summaries, same time step]

Here I was accidentally (manually!) storing validation summaries during training runs and then *again* in a separate validation run.

Also I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to go about it, but it certainly works.